# Protege - SPARQL Query tab appearing blank

Tags: sparql, protege

I am working on the Protege, I was trying to run a query on SPARQL Query. However, when I open the tab nothing is displayed. Would someone be able to help

[image: I have included an image]

I have tried to sync the reasoner, close and open the application but none of these steps have solved the problem

Comment: which Protege version? Any plugins installed? What does the Protege log say? How large is the ontology?